# Webpack Alias Module not found

Tags: webpack

webpack.config.js

```
root: __dirname,
alias:{
    Core: 'app/components/Core.jsx'
},
```

On the file being used.

```
var Core = require('Core');
```

My file structure is.

-root

--app

--- components

Tried different solutions like changing to root to path.resolve(__dirname) and stuff like removing root and adding abslolute paths to the aliases, Still getting module not found.

Answer (score 0):

`alias` property must be inside `resolve` property. Therefore your webpack config should look like:

```
resolve: {
   alias:{
      Core: 'app/components/Core.jsx'
   }
}
```

Additionally you may use an absolute path using `path.resolve` to follow the best practices.